# Can't find iOS FaceTime protocol documentation

Tags: iphone, facetime

As per the title. I searched all through the Apple website, and cannot find anything about it. I am not an iPhone developer member (yet) so don't have access to that stuff. I just want to develop an Android application that can talk with the FaceTime protocol.

It would be a bit silly if we all had to pay Apple just to view the FaceTime documentation to implement the protocol in our non-iOS applications.

Comment: From what I can tell, the specs have not been released yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The docs for facetime are not yet available. You're not missing anything.

Comment: You are correct, there are no docs (currently). BUT you can facetime from a URL.  eg facetime://5555555555  to see if this works. Just open Safari on the iPhone and type that URL hit enter and it will work. iPhone ios 4.1

Comment: Sure, but that's not the FaceTime protocol spec now, is it?

Comment: If you just want the ports involved (obviously that's not the same as the protocols), Apple has posted those at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4245

Answer (score 7):

Apple has been unable to release it as an open standard [because of the patent battle it lost](http://www.imore.com/why-facetime-quality-might-have-dropped-why-apple-still-hasnt-released-it-open-standard-and-patent).

There is [community documentation of the protocol](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/FaceTime), including this series of blog posts:

**Special Look: Face Time**

- [part 1: Introduction](http://www.packetstan.com/2010/07/special-look-face-time-part-1.html)
- [part 2: SIP and Data Streams](http://www.packetstan.com/2010/07/special-look-face-time-part-2-sip-and.html)
- [part 3: Call Connection Initialization](http://www.packetstan.com/2010/07/special-look-face-time-part-3-call.html)

Answer (score 6):

At least to get started, take a look at this for the list of IETF standards used by Facetime:  http://blog.imtc.org/index.php/2010/06/09/the-technology-behind-apples-facetime-standards/

Additionally, Apple has said it will be submitting Facetime as an open standard - so there should be more documentation on how all these standards glue together in Facetime. .  anyone know when this will come out?

Answer (score 4):

**Update** 
You don't have to pay to test on devices as of 2015. Payment is required to deploy on the app store, get beta access and sundry other stuff as per [Apple's page](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

**Original**
You don't have to pay to get the SDK, just to be able to test on devices